# Safari flex child horizontal scrollbar over content (incorrect content height)

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox, scrollbar

I am creating a horizontally scrolled div (flex child) with child items.

It works great everywhere except in Safari.

It might not show the problem here on the StackOverflow code sample, because it is dependent on height properties of "all" parents. That is why I am setting html and body to height 100%.

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    #flexCont {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #scrollable {
        height:150px;
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        overflow-x:scroll;

        /* just for visualization */
        border:1px solid black;
        width:250px;
    }

    .item {
        display: inline-block;
        height:100%;

        /* just for visualization */
        border-bottom:15px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-right:5px;
        width:50px;
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    
    <div id="flexCont">
    <div id="scrollable">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The issue is that Safari sets the `.item`'s height to 100% of `#scrollable`'s height (150px) even though the horizontal scrollbar is shown and the content area is smaller (135px).

It results in scrollbar appearing over the content.

Chrome and other correctly set the `.item`'s height to 135px as expected (assuming 15px for scrollbar).

As mentioned, it is dependent on height property of all parents. Meaning if I remove `height 100%` from `html`, `body` or `#flexCont` it renders correctly. Furthermore if I remove `display flex` or at least `flex-direction column`, it renders correctly as well.

I have added the bottom black borders to better visualize it. If they cannot be seen, they are hidden behind the scrollbar.

Any idea how to fix it?

Bottom 15px (black) visible on Chrome and behind scrollbar on Safari.

[image: Correct on Chrome - bottom 15px border is visible]
[image: Incorrect on Safari - bottom 15px border is behind scrollbar]

Edit: Damn Safari... adding `border-bottom` and `box-sizing` creates another issue (at least) when attempting to fix it with `max-height:fill-available`. Solutions must be tested without the border.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Chrome and Safari's `.item`'s are both 150px, as expected.

Comment: @Mattijs 150px is not expected if scrollbar is shown. The `#scrollable` is 150px in height, scrollbar should take 15px and so the content (`.item`s) should be 135px; And setting `calc(100% - 15px)` makes it 15px short everywhere except Safari.

Comment: On macOS and iOS scrollbars overlay, without taking up any space, as if they were positioned absolutely.

Comment: As mentioned, when I remove `height 100%` from parents or remove `display flex`, it does not occur. That would be strange behaviour either way.

Comment: Ah okay I see the inconsistency now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding `height: fill-available;` to the `.item`'s seems to fix the issue.

```
.item {
    height: 100%;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Edit:
Removed `-moz-fill-available` and `fill-available` as they are not neccessary to fix the issue in Safari and are breaking layout in Firefox.
Furthermore note that in Safari, you have to use -webkit-fill-available for all children of `.item` if you want them to have height based on their parent (`.item`), which creates further issues.

Comment: Damn, it works, but only when the bottom border is present. If it is removed, it breaks again. Did not expect that.

Comment: Omg, try keeping the `box-sizing border box` and try different (higher) pixel values for bottom-border... it goes crazy.

Comment: Haha I didn't realise. I have updated my answer with a solution that seems to work without the border now!

Comment: Let me add to it a bit. `-webkit-` prefix "fixes" the issue in Safari, but `-moz-` breaks it in Firefox. Furthermore in browsers that accept the `fill-available` value, if you want `.item` to have 100% height child, you have to keep using `fill-available` for those children. So unfortunatelly it has trade offs. So I would keep only `-webkit-` prefixed property and `100%` as fallback,which fixes it in Safari while not breaking it anywhere else. I will report it as a webkit bug, which is probably the best solution in long run.